# attempt to index upvalue 'letter' error because or arr_str[i]

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

Im trying to create a random letter answer for my game but the problem is that it wont detect the images please help...

```
local s = answer --answer
local len = string.len(answer)
local str 
local j

for j=1,len do
    str = s:sub(j,j)
    arr_str[j]= str 
end

    for i = 1, #arr_str do
        local j = math.random( 1,#arr_str)
        arr_str[i], arr_str[j] = arr_str[j], arr_str[i]
    end

local max = #arr_str
local rowMax = max
--if max > 8 then rowMax = 8 end
local gap = 35
local xPos = halfW - (rowMax/2*35) + 17.5
local yPos = bottom - 20
local startpos = xPos



for i= 1, #arr_str do

    slot = display.newImageRect( "images/bg_slot.png", 43, 43 )
    slot.x = xPos; slot.y = yPos -40
    slotgroup:insert( slot )

    slot1 = display.newImageRect( "images/ans_slot.png", 43, 43 )
    slot1.x = xPos; slot1.y = yPos 
    slotgroup:insert( slot1)

    print("ERROR",arr_str[i])
    letter = display.newImageRect("letters/uc/".. arr_str[i] ..".png",50,50)    
    letter.name = arr_str[i] 
    letter.x = xPos; letter.y = yPos
    letter.idBg = i
    lettergroup:insert( letter)

    xPos = xPos + gap
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image that you are trying to open does not exist.

Print the whole path of the image (code below) and look for it on your project folder to make sure you really have that image (pay attention to the file extension as well.

```
print("letters/uc/".. arr_str[i] ..".png")
```

Comment: Alreay fix the problem thanks for the answer..really appreciate it.